# Css changes are not being applied in rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I am working on rails app and now I am having trouble.

> Early when I use to change my frontend styling and apply changes in css then they quickly show up on reload in brower.

> But in present, don't know but something went wrong. Whenever I change css and save it then onload, things remain same.
> After debugging, I found that app is picking styling files from precompiled assets pipeline. So for the solution, I have to recompile the assets then 2 new files are generated against wach file changed. And there will be 4 files in total against a single css file in which changes are made. So now I have to delete old ones and then have to restart the serve and refreshing the browser will show all the changing and that is weird as I have to do it all the time for every single change.
> I can't figure as I am new to rails. Help....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I have find out the reason and it was because I have run the command of assets precompile which I shouldn't have to run as rails was doing it already for me may be due to configuration of my project or may it is its default behavior.

> To solve this problem I have to delete my projects folder from my system and clone it again and things got normal again.

And now I never ever going to run assets precompile command again

Comment: guys this is not the right way, follow the below answer.
Please don't give answers which are not the right solution to the question.

Comment: @pavankumarv Sorry to say but I have shared what worked for me and what was the reason for this issue. It might be different in your case. Can you please tell me what is wrong in it? If not then please not mark this answer as useless as it is working one.

Answer (score 4):

Please clear the tmp cache first and then run the server

```
$ rake tmp:cache:clear && rails server
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing the app, you should delete `public/assets` directory. Then restart the app. Don't run `asssts:precompile` task. Your most recent changes of assets will be up to date without restart the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a solution : run  `rake assets:clobber`, it will remove the precompiled  css and js. Then run  `yarn build --watch` to build back the css and js file.

Dont run the `assets:build` as the same issue will revert.

Comment: this answer worked for me. mark this correct!

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7 comes with [dart-sass](https://sasscss.org/documentation/cli) by default. When the project is started with `./bin/dev`, it starts the script "build:css" from **package.json**:

```
# My "build:css" script in package.json is:
sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules
```

According to the `sass` cli documentation, there is [an option](https://sasscss.org/documentation/cli/dart-sass#load-path) `--load-path`

> This option (abbreviated -I) adds an additional load path for Sass to look for stylesheets. It can be passed multiple times to provide multiple load paths.

So in my case, I added  `--load-path=./app/components` to the sass command in my `package.json` file (because I have custom scss files in my ./app/components directory).

```
# My package.json scripts after adding the '--load-path=./app/components' option:
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --load-path=./app/components"
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be a browser issue, where the browser is caching the previous CSS and not reloading your new CSS changes.

Instead of reloading the page with CTRL+R, try reloading the page with CTRL+SHIFT+R

This will force a reload of the web page and clear the page cache, which forces all the assets to reload and fixed the problem for me.

No need to run css:clobber, assets:precompile, or anything like that! Just change the way you reload your browser :)